# How to express multiple key value pairs in an Alias or function?

Tags: bash, function, alias

Take a look at this command:

```
vault kv put {mypath) key1=value1 key2=value2 ... keyN=valueN
```

I tried the following:

```
vput() {
    vault kv put $1 '@'='@'
}
```

but obviously this is not working.

I want to be able to eventually type something like this:

```
vput {myPath} key1 value1 key2 value2 keyN valueN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no easy way of doing it.
You need to rebuild args manually, like using an array, a loop, and shift:

```
vput() {
  args=("$1")
  shift

  while (( $# )); do
    args+=("$1=$2")
    shift 2
  done

  vault kv put "${args[@]}"
}
```